# How to display tick mark on console using java 7?

Tags: java

I am using `\u2713` Unicode but it always shows a question on the console.

I am unable to print tick marks on the console. Unicode Characters appear as question marks on the console.

How do I print a tick mar on the console?

Comment: go through  this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ-pnhtuXnAhVGfisKHbVzBdEQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Feclipsesource.com%2Fblogs%2F2013%2F02%2F21%2Fpro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console%2F&usg=AOvVaw3S9d8hUqZCZgLyWz1_dNW4

Comment: By “console” do you mean a Windows command window?

Answer (score 1):

It works out of the box on my Linux laptop.
[image]

So your issue is possibly related to the settings of your console. The `env` command outputs `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to print this on your eclipse console, then try this.

1. In Eclipse, right click on your application class, and choose Run As –> Run Configurations
2. In Common tab, Encoding group, click on the “Other” and select the UTF-8.

[image]